# When to use named and called?

Tags: american-english, writing, writing-style, letter-writing

I am writing my Statement of Purpose. I am writing a sentence such as

> *I moved to a small town called Falmouth where I* ....

Should I use *named* or *called*?

> *I moved to a small town named Falmouth where I* ....

Comment: I'd use neither: _I moved to the small town of Falmouth where I..._

Comment: @J.R. Pray, why?

Comment: Any of those mentioned would be idiomatic. *Small town called*, *small town named*, *small town of*, but as a native speaker I tend to agree with J.R. that the last one is best.